# China visa 3rd country rule

Tags: visas, transit, china, us-citizens, transit-visas

I will be traveling to Korea in a few months with a layover in Shanghai. Looking over the visa requirements for US citizens in Wikipedia, it says I do not need a visa if I am traveling to a third country in this case Korea. Because it is China and all, I want to confirm that I do not need a visa for China in this situation. Should I even go a step further to confirm this rule by calling the consulate? I don't want to get there and find out I can't continue my trip because of something I overlooked.

Edit: I am a US Citizen and my layover is less than 4 hours.

Comment: I assume you have a short layover inbetween two flights on the same ticket and you will be perfectly fine.

Comment: Voting as a duplicate at the moment. Although it depends on your citizenship which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @CMaster: Since the OP is explicitly mentioning "visa requirements for US citizens", it seems to be implied that he is one.

Comment: I edited with the relevant information from the comments. Again, I am more than certain that I won't have an issue but I wanted to ask to make sure.